# how to download m3u8 stream with query?

Tags: video-streaming

I have Downloaded classic m3u8 links that ends with m3u8 like
xxx.yyy.zz/aaa.m3u8

that contains no query. with vlc player. I am ok with this type.

Now I have a problem with m3u8 link than contains query, like :

https://xxx.yyy.zz/stream.m3u8?path=dlv/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd_720p_0003.ts&expires=1677741364&signature=02cfe5142ed543dcbf4c96f24b3ca1f4.m3u8

dose anyone have any idea how can I download this type of m3u8 link. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference - it should just work.

Except this link is designed to expire. Notice the `expires=1677741364` part. The number 1677741364 is a Unix timestamp pointing at March 2, 2023 07:16:04.

You can try fiddling with the link, but if the signature that follows the expiration timestamp is implemented correctly then there's nothing you can do to revive an expired link.

Comment: actually it doesnt work, maybe its bcs of the timestamp. can I change the timestamp? @gronostaj

Comment: I Changed the timestamp but it didnt work

Comment: @MehdiM changing the timestamp will do nothing if the actual file on the server gets deleted at the time when the address/m3u8 expires.

Comment: @MehdiM Read the answer again. I have explained why it doesn't work and why changing the timestamp won't work either.